# Superficial friends just act like they care about each other. What do you guys call this behavior?

Tags: word-request

They just fake smiles to each other, practice hypocrisy or just pretend to be kind or polite. Is it idiomatic to call this interactions "putting on a phony show " or "acting to be kind" or something?

Comment: can I use ingratiating?

Comment: Have you looked it up in the dictionary? Does the definition you find suit your purpose?

Comment: NO， I haven't found any。I just saw the translation and find them weird.

Comment: If the person who they are pretending to be nice to is in a higher position than them, you might use the word sycophant or yes-man.

Comment: idiom: to put on an act

Comment: [to be hypocritical, not practice it]

Answer (score 1):

One name for this behaviour is *disingenuity* or *disingenuousness*, although it is more common to use the related adjective and say that a person is being *[disingenuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)*.

It means giving a false appearance; having behaviour or words that conceal real feelings.

Comment: Yes, that's high register in my book.

Answer (score -2):

These sorts are often quite simply called "fake friends" in the U.S.

Comment: That's not the name of the behaviour and does not answer the OP's question.